# Pasar parametros onclick android

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

Quisiera saber como puedo pasar diferentes parametroa a un onclick en android, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
idRespuesta= operaciones_que_calculo;
for (k=0;k<5;k++){
Button Respuesta = new Button(contexto);
    Respuesta.setText("Ver Respuesta");
    Respuesta.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.coloBoton));
    layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(380, 90);
    layout.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
    Respuesta.setLayoutParams(layout);
                            
     Respuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
                 verRespuesta(idRespuesta,k);
                 }
         });
.....
}
```

El tema esta en que dentro de ver respuesta la k siempre vale 5 independientemente del boton que pinche e idRespuesta toma el ultimo valor.

Comment: que es lo que quieres hacer? al hacer click saber cual se presiono?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que al pinchar en el botón llame a una función a la que le paso dos parámetros para poder trabajar con ellos.

Comment: @gustavohernandez me perdí, ya no te entiendo que quieres solucionar. Tienes en teoría un ciclo que se ejecuta 4 veces. `idRespuesta` almacenará por lo tanto el resultado del último ciclo. Ahora tienes en teoría 5 botones del siguiente ciclo. Mi suposición es que generas los resultados en el primer ciclo y deberias de visualizarlos en el segundo ciclo es algo así? Por favor amplia el código y lo que intentas hacer con él para dejar más claro el código la pregunta y que la comunidad te pueda ayudar. saludos

Comment: Tengo un for en el que calculo 4 idRespuestas pero para cada for hay otro que se ejecuta 5 veces, y en total hay 20 botones y en cada botón quiero que al pinchar se pasen dos valores diferentes el idRespuesta y el k.

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a la comunidad. 
El problema lo tienes con el ciclo. El valor de `k` siempre cambia por cada ciclo y no lo estas guardando en ningún lugar.

Ahora esta confusión se da porque estas asignando el evento `setOnClickListener` a cada botón pero el evento no esta guardando el valor de `k`. Por lo que sin importar el botón que toques cuando se ejecute el onclick toma el valor con que terminó el ciclo.

Una solución posible es almacenar el valor de `k` en cada botón. De la siguiente manera:

```
Button Respuesta ;

        for (k=0;k<5;k++){
            Respuesta = new Button(contexto);
            Respuesta.setText("Ver Respuesta");
            Respuesta.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.coloBoton));
            layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(380, 90);
            layout.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
            Respuesta.setLayoutParams(layout);

            Respuesta.setTag(k);//a cada boton le agregas un tag
            Respuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int valorK = (Integer) view.getTag();//tomas el tag asignado
                    verRespuesta(idRespuesta, valorK);
                }
            });

.....

        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion, el problema es que tambien me haria falta pasar el idRespuesta, el cual tambien cambia.
`código`
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
idRespuesta= "mis operaciones";
for (k=0;k<5;k++){
Button Respuesta = new Button(contexto);
    Respuesta.setText("Ver Respuesta");
    Respuesta.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.coloBoton));
    layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(380, 90);
....

Comment: No coloques el código en comentarios mejor edita la pregunta y agregas el código a la pregunta. @gustavohernandez. Ya luego que edites la pregunta me consultas

Comment: Lo acabo de modificar, gracias. Me estaba planteando hacer una lista y asi acceder a la posición de la lista con el tag que me indicas, aunque me parece un poco chapuza.

Answer (score 0):

El listener se lo puedes asignar al botón en lugar del layout que lo contiene, el valor de "k", asignalo como tag a la vista para que lo puedas obtener correctamente.

Ejemplo:

```
...
Respuesta.setTag(k);
Respuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    verRespuesta(idRespuesta, (Integer) view.getTag());
                }
            }); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

He modificado la pregunta original pues me haría falta pasar dos parametros ,espero que ahora quede mas claro. Gracias.

Al final lo he modificado y solucionado de esta forma

```js
Respuesta.setTag(idRespuesta+";"+k);
Respuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    String etiqueta=(String) view.getTag();
                                    String[] parametros=etiqueta.split(";");
                                    prf.verRespuesta(parametros[0],parametros[1]);
                                }
                            });
```